# Trying to get the sum for each Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have been trying to figure this out, but I seem to be going nowhere. Basically I have a JSON that outputs.

```
[
      {
"gosuResponse" : {
"tokenId" : "60e2d532-3d1c-4a95-adbd-aa352984c125",
"page" : 1,
"pageSize" : 1000,
"nbLinesTotal" : 15,
"serials" : {
  "serial" : [ "272072207980" ]
},
"data" : {
  "row" : [ {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "", "1"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "BNP-Blogs", "1504"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "BNP", "66"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "GOOMPlayer-Site", "6"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "podcast", "19"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-10", "stream", "10"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "", "6"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "BNP-Blogs", "1742"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "BNP", "61"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "GOOMPlayer-Site", "2"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "podcast", "18"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-09", "stream", "8"]
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-08", "", "7"]      
  }, {
    "col" : [ "2015-02-01", "stream", "8"]
  } ]
 }
}
}
]
```

Since there are similar names, I grouped them together using underscore.js

```
var items = result[0].gosuResponse.data.row;

    var groups = _(items).groupBy(function(o) {
        return o.col[1];
    });
    console.log(groups);
```

This outputs,

```
Object 
 - BNP : Array[4]
   - 0 : Object
     - col : Array[3]
       0 : '2015-02-10"
       1 : 'BNP'
       2:  '66'
   - 1 : Object
     - col : Array[3]
       0 : '2015-02-10"
       1 : 'BNP'
       2:  '66'
```

I am trying to add up the number value in position 2 for each Object.

I tested with one key in my Plunkr, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it for all objects?

My Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nNwNoAiUz4PKV8ucaPc1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no reasons to group items:

```
var sum = {};
_.each(items, function(row) {
  var col = row.col;
  if (sum.hasOwnProperty(col[1])) {
    sum[col[1]] += parseInt(col[2]) || 0;
  } else {
    sum[col[1]] = parseInt(col[2]) || 0;
  }
});
```

But note I'm relatively new to underscore.js and did not know much about its specific tricks.

Update:
I've found a native underscore.js solution with using groups also:

```
var groups = _(items).groupBy(function(o) {
    return o.col[1];
});

var sum2 = {};
_.each(groups, function(group, key) {
  sum2[key] = _.reduce(group, function(memo, item) {
    return memo + (parseInt(item.col[2]) || 0);
  }, 0);
});
```